# How to hide folders except mentioned in config spec?

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

We are trying to have only few folders in our dynamic view.

For that we have written clearcase config spec like below.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /Process/Projects/OurProject\... /main/LATEST
element "/Process/Projects/OurProject 100/..." /main/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

But it displays all the other folder also , only thing is we are not able to open those folders. Is it possible to hide the all other folders which are not mentioned in config spec ( I know that in snapshot view we can do this by adding load rule, but we wanted it to be done in dynamic view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
element /Process/Projects/* -none
```

You must add that rule *after* the ones selecting the directories that you want:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /Process/Projects/OurProject\... /main/LATEST
element "/Process/Projects/OurProject 100/..." /main/LATEST
element /Process/Projects/* -none
element * /main/LATEST
```

Note the '`*`': all the element within Projects will be ignored, but Project itself must be selected by a selection rule.

If you used:

```
element /Process/Projects/... -none
```

You wouldn't see *anything* in `Project`, because `Project` itself would be ignored, making its content non-visible (and not eligible to the other selection rules of your config spec).

Comment: I was appreciated by my manager for this. Thanks Vonc for your help

Comment: @Samselvaprabu now that put a smile on my face ;) You are welcome.