# How can I view the private files in a folder at Clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have a usecase in IBM Rational ClearCase, I have a folder with the name `SRC` and there is checked in the C source files, which are generated with Simulink ecoder.

Now I want to change my config spec so I cannot see in `SRC` folder the checked in files but the private files, so I could force Simulink to generate fresh source files.

How could I do this in config spec ?

I tried to use the command `element /f_01/.../src/... NOLABEL` to see only the private files because the label `NOLABEL` does not exist, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your view: [snapshot (web view if ClearTeam 8+)or dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309).

For snapshot view, one trick would simply to change your load rules in order to *not* load a folder.

But a more general way (for any view) would be to not select any version of a folder: see "[How to hide folders except mentioned in config spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579141/6309)"

```
element /path/to/src/* -none
```

Comment: Thank you, ClearCase is fantastic!!

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that there will be side effects if you then put the config spec back. You will have "eclipsed" files...

You may want to use cleartool checkout -ptime to keep the timestamps on the files and then regenerate the source. If the tool uses timestamps, and the source is older than the files it's generated from, this could work too.  You could also get "cute" and delete the checked out files and then regenerate the source.

There is almost always more than one way to accomplish anything in clearcase...