# How to restrain my ClearCase view to only a subset of the dir of one of the vobs?

Tags: performance, subset, clearcase

My Clearcase **dynamic** view has to access several vobs. But one of the vob has very large number of directory, so I wandered if I could tune my dynamic view to access only a list of directories of that specific vob - believing this could improve performances of my searches.

How do I do?

Say here are my vobs below, and in the last, the list of dir I want:

```
vob1
vob2
large_vob
   /dir17
   /dir31
   /dir53
```

Here is my basic view:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
element -directory * /main/LATEST
```

Shall I go in some direction like the below?

```
element /vob1/* CHECKEDOUT
element /vob1/* /main/LATEST
element -directory /vob1/* /main/LATEST
...
element /large_vob/dir17/* CHECKEDOUT
element /large_vob/dir17/* /main/LATEST
element -directory /large_vob/dir17/* /main/LATEST
...
```

But I got error

> Encountered an improper argument

... plus this above looks to me like hard to maintain. Is there any other way, like a context inside of view declaration? --- Ideally I would like to only work with one view.

I am **not admin**, I would also like avoiding per-user read restriction or anything.

Any help appreciated!

### edit

Restraining the number of directories in my view's vob did improved full-vob label search performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option that you can try is to apply [some "none" version section to your folder in your config spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346985/6309).

If the folder is not selected (version "none"), then it won't try to select (or, hopefully, to search) its content.

```
element /large_vob/dir17/... -none
```

(no need for '`/*`' here: I want to not select the folder itself: see "[How to hide folders except mentioned in config spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579141/6309)")

The [OP J. Chomel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6019417/j-chomel) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623422/how-to-restrain-my-clearcase-view-to-only-a-subset-of-the-dir-of-one-of-the-vobs/36623727?noredirect=1#comment60848241_36623727) making it work with adding the expected directories like:

```
element /large_vob/dir17/... /main/LATEST
element /large_vob/dir18/* -none
element * /main/LATEST
```

The order of a config spec is important.

Comment: Many thanks! This sounds like a great possibility, but it goes on displaying the folders I _unselected_ with `-none`. When I browse the directories, the file and subdirs are still there. Maybe I should have precised I use Dynamic views. Is it possible to make the directories disappear from the vob (like magic)

Comment: @J.Chomel Indeed, the folder are there, but empty (/main/0). Let me check.

Comment: @J.Chomel Can you try again with the syntax I mention in my edited answer?

Comment: I tried, and am still able to browse inside `dir17` even though I added `/...` after the path. If it is of any relevance, I use **Rational ClearCase Explorer 8.0.0.2**

Comment: It worked when I added the directories I want before like that: `element /large_vob/dir17/... /main/LATEST`, then that I do not want the others
`element /large_vob/* -none`, then again
`element * /main/LATEST`

Comment: @J.Chomel Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.